# Javascript Looping h2 into li elemen html

Tags: javascript, loops

how to loop in javascript li and h2?

```
innerHTML = json.records[i].noitem;
and
innerHTML = json.records[i].year;
```

my script :

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.records.length; i++) {
no idea
}
```

to this :

```
<ul>
 <li><h2>noitem 1</h2> year 1</li>
 <li><h2>noitem 2</h2> year 2</li>
 <li><h2>noitem 3</h2> year 3</li>
 <li><h2>noitem 4</h2> year 4</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Could you be a little more clear about what you want to accomplish?

Comment: [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild),
[`Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: show item like that bro.... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7VqxZycUNH6NWdMc0ZfZEhocm1HTHhRT21LMlNyZFJiWU5n/view

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do, is grab each `json.records[i]...` and output it or add it to a variable, once you do that, you get:

```
var out="<ul>";
for (var i = 0; i < json.records.length; i++) {
    out+="<li><h2>"+json.records[i].noitem+"</h2> "+json.records[i].year+"</li>";
}
out+="</ul>";
```